# Connect to SOAP using JAX WS

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I want to build a soap client in java using JAXWS. I searched on google but didn't find any relevant information. Here is what I have tried:

```
     QName serviceName = new QName("urn:Site", "Site");
     QName portName = new QName("urn:Site", "Server_HandlerPort");
     String  endpointAddress = "http://myhost/url/soap";
     Service service = Service.create(serviceName);
     service.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointAddress);
     Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
     BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) dispatch;
     MessageFactory factory = ((SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding()).getMessageFactory();
     SOAPMessage request = factory.createMessage();
     SOAPHeader header = request.getSOAPHeader();
     SOAPBody body = request.getSOAPBody();
     QName payloadName = new QName("session");
     SOAPBodyElement payload = body.addBodyElement(payloadName); 
     SOAPMessage reply = null;
     try {
        reply = dispatch.invoke(request);
    } catch (WebServiceException wse){
        wse.printStackTrace();
    }

    body = reply.getSOAPBody();
    QName responseName = new QName("urn:site","sessionResponse");
    SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) body.getChildElements(responseName).next();
    System.out.println(bodyElement.getValue());
```

This do not work. This always returns `null` I'm not sure why? Can anyone help me on this? Any example? for doing such thing?

Comment: Any errors/stacktraces ?

Comment: @Santosh: no. there is no errors.

Answer (score 5):

JAX-WS allows you to generate a client from the web service's WSDL using wsimport.
This will make the client code much simpler.
Here's a sample [tutorial](http://justjavajee.wordpress.com/2008/09/29/jax-ws-tutorial-part-i/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I noticed, the unmarshalling that occurs in `dispatch.invoke` of a response does not populate the body, envelope etc. from `SOAPMessage`, but instead it creates an internal `Document` that it is linked to the `SOAPPart`.

If you invoke `reply.writeTo(System.out)` after the invoke is called, it will print the full response message into console.

You can browse the `Document` (in this case actually the root `Element`) and get your `sessionResponse`. Here is an code snippet:

```
NodeList nodeList = reply.getSOAPPart().getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:site", "sessionResponse");
Node node = nodeList.item(0);
```

Now depending on the structure of the response, you may need to do some navigation in the tree. Let's suppose that your response looks like this:

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:sessionResponse xmlns:ns2="urn:site">
      <return>Hello World!</return>
    </ns2:sessionResponse >
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

In order to get the returned value you will call:

```
System.out.println(node.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

- 1st getFirstChild returns `return` Node
- 2nd getFirstChild returns `text` Node

If you need the `Document` object instead of `Element` object from the `SOAPPart` you need to cast the `SOAPPart` to `SOAPPartImpl`:

```
Document document = ((SOAPPartImpl) response.getSOAPPart()).getDocument();
```