# Dynamically change endpoint address in WSO2 ESB

Tags: dynamic, wso2, uri, endpoint, wso2-esb

How can I set the endpoint address dynamically?

I set endpoint address in a property at runtime, and need to replace the URI of endpoint address with its value.

How can I set the URI value of address with this value?

Answer (score 5):

You can create your endpoint like

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="MyEndpoint">
   <http uri-template="{uri.var.full}?f={uri.var.f}{+uri.var.extra}" method="put">
   </http>
</endpoint>
```

Then before calling the endpoint 'MyEndpoint' set the properties
.. the properties, to be parsed for an endpoint must begin with uri.

I also found out, that if you put a + before the property name, it doesn't URI encode it, so it's handy for creating parameters on the fly.. otherwise for known parameters, you can do like above for paramameter f

so .. something like

```
<property name="uri.var.full" value="http://jarhedz.com/viewtopic.php"/>
<property name="url.var.f" value="2"/>
<property name="uri.var.extra" value="&t=39"/>
<send>
    <endpoint key="MyEndpoint"></endpoint>
</send>
```

should bring you to the url http://jarhedz.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=39

(btw just as a note, if you're using the web editor, it'll complain about the & .. its buggy as hell .. save it as

```
&amp;
```

.. and that saves it as & or set the property using javascript )

Comment: If the URI is not http?

Answer (score 2):

Use Header meditaor to set "to" header and use default endpoint..Check [this post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/defining-dynamic-endpoint-in-wso2esb.html) for sample.

Comment: That sample worked for me! The only change I did to make it work was to remove the <endpoint> and <default> tags from the top, and add them inside a <send> tag at the bottom. It'd look like this: <header xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"   name="To" expression="fn:concat(get-property('server'),get-property('service'))"/><send><endpoint><default/></endpoint></send></inSequence>

Answer (score 1):

Use [header mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Header+Mediator) to set the "To" Address header with the value you extract from your assigned property.

Comment: Thank you Mr **Shelan Perera** for your quick response. i used header mediator for this issue but i want to use End Point artifact so that i had more flexibility if require. how can i use xpath expression in endpoint? i used endpoint template but when i create endpoint from the template in console, only can set Value field not Expression in it's parameter.
also i create EndPoint bye address and set Expression with get-property('EPadd') but  it does not work. i do not know what should be written in the Xpath field when creating an EndPopint!

Answer (score 0):

When the server doesn't publish its WSDL, see Myobis comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490737/how-to-change-webservice-url-endpoint).  Tried [addPort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646591/connect-to-soap-using-jax-ws) without success.

Answer (score 0):

This method is worked for me correctly.

I need to create bellow dynamic url

> http://localhost:8787/{**dynamic parameter**}

Inside the end point url is like this

> http://localhost:8787/{uri.var.servicepath}

Set "**test**" variable as my **dynamic parameter** (If you need to set Expression value set it). Set "test" value inside the property mediator.(I did this insideproxy service)

```
<property name="uri.var.servicepath" scope="default" type="STRING" value="test"/>
```

create endpoint

In here I created HTTP End point

```
<endpoint name="ServiceEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8787/{uri.var.servicepath}"/>
</endpoint>
```

Then add this endpoint inside your Proxy service or API

```
<send>
   <endpoint key="ServiceEP"/>
</send>
```

Finally your proxy look like this

```
<inSequence>
   <property name="uri.var.servicepath" scope="default" type="STRING" 
   value="test"/>

   <send>
      <endpoint key="SurepayVASAppsEP"/>
    </send>
</inSequence>
```

Like this you can change every url parameter.Ex-:

> http://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.port}/{uri.var.servicepath}

Answer (score 0):

Another way to dynamically change the target endpoint url is through the use of the [REST_URL_POSTFIX](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/property-reference/http-transport-properties/#rest_url_postfix) property.