# WSO2 ESB append string to endpoint url during message transport

Tags: url-rewriting, wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

in my use case I have this proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="MIOProxy"
   transports="https,http"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <sequence name="blackListCheck"/>
         <send>
             <failover>
        <enpoint key="workerClusterTest" />
                <enpoint key="replica_test" />
              </failover>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

where the endpoint workerClusterTest has this configuration:

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="workerClusterTest">
   <property name="class" value="worker" scope="axis2"/>
   <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
      <endpoint>
         <address url="http://localhost:8080/myservice1" />
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint>
         <address url="http://localhost:8080/myservice2" />
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint>
         <address url="http://localhost:8080/myservice3" />
      </endpoint>
   </loadbalance>
</endpoint>
```

While the message is reaching the workerClusterTest endpoint or the replicaTest, i want to insert in their address url a string: "MyString".
Precisely if the message is sent to the workerClusterTest endpoint i want that its url

```
url="http://localhost:8080/myservice1"
```

to become

```
url="http://localhost:8080/MyString/myservice1"
```

is there a way in the inSequence to do this directly? Or a custom class mediator is the best way?

Comment: So according to above you define 2 endpoints workerClusterTest and replica_test separately. Then why can't you add the required string in the endpoint definition itself?

Comment: it's a requirement of the architecture... i mean that the two endpoint are global... while the incoming request regard specific services whose url address are like: http://localhost:8080/MyString/myservice1;http://localhost:8080/MyString1/myservice1; http://localhost:8080/MyString2/myservice1 ... i want to know if i can avoid to repeat a lot of times the endpoint definitions, just keeping those two and then concatenating MyString-1-2-3 to them

Comment: not really sure but isn't this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876410/wso2-esb-dynamically-change-endpoint-address

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this within inSequence. You have to write a custom class mediator to achieve your needs.