# WSO2 ESB - how to dynamically set value to WSDL Endpoint URI using Property Meditor

Tags: variables, wsdl, wso2, esb, endpoint

I have an endpoint (WSDL) with following settings:

```
<endpoint>
    <wsdl port="portName" 
          service="serviceName"
          uri="http://example.com/services/service1.wsdl"/>
</endpoint>
```

And I have a separate xml file containing my settings for those 3 attributes: uri, service, and port. I can get their value from the xml.

```
<property expression="get-property('registry','gov:trunk/services/Config.xml')"
       name="gc" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:gc//wsdl//uri" name="uri"/>
    <property expression="$ctx:gc//wsdl//service" name="service"/>
    <property expression="$ctx:gc//wsdl//port" name="port"/>
 </log>
```

Now, my question is: how do I set those 3 values dynamically to my endpoint?

I only need this endpoint once, and there is no need to create template for this purpose, but I can't find any resource to help me do that.

Can anyone share some knowledge and experience?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 ESB : DYNAMICALLY CHANGE ENDPOINT ADDRESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876410/wso2-esb-dynamically-change-endpoint-address)

Comment: I am using WSDL endpoint which has no attribute called "uri-template" or what so ever. I need to dynamically change the wsdl endpoint uri/service/port.